# How can a build an XML tree in VB.NET reading the element names from a text file?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, dom

What I'm trying to do is more complex than this, but I'm trying to get over this hurdle.

Let's say I had a text file that had these contents:

```
LINE1
LINE2
LINE3
```

And I wanted each of these lines to be converted to an XML file that had each line as a child element of the previous line.
The output should be:

```
<LINE1>
         <LINE2>
           <LINE3>
           </LINE3>
         </LINE2>
</LINE1>
```

I've tried several approaches using Linq to XML and XML DOM and I always get this:

```
<LINE1>
   <LINE2>
   <LINE3>
</LINE1> or some variation of that.
```

It doesn't seem to support a deep tree. 
I have read pages of pages of various books on LINQ to XML and some articles on XML DOM. 
It seems like I could have spent that time writing a program in VB.NET that would just write out text using StreamWriter. 
I thought I had a breakthrough when I found you could just use the .ADD method and not specify the element.
I wish I could show you some code, but it's really convoluted.
To keep this simple I'll add some simple code then my other code.
But I'm trying to do much much more with my code than this example.

```vb
Private Sub BuildTree()
      Dim elementList As New StreamReader("c:\thisfile.txt")
      'The file contents vary
      Do While elementList.Peek() >= 0
           ' code here to build the xml
           ' each line would add a new element that would be a child
           ' of the previous element
      Loop
      ' Desired results "nested" elements
      '<LINE1>
      '   <LINE2>
      '     <LINE3>
      '     </LINE3>
      '   </LINE2>
      '</LINE1>
 End Sub

' Here is the the code that I was experimenting with:
' I would get an object not set to a reference of an object error
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
      Dim isaElement As New XElement("DOC")
      Dim element2Add As New XElement("NONAME")
      element2Add.Name = isaElement.Name
      Dim elementNames As New ArrayList
      elementNames.Add("ISA")
      elementNames.Add("GS")
      elementNames.Add("ST")
      Dim lastElement As New XElement("LAST")

      Dim i As Integer = 0
      For i = 0 To elementNames.Count - 1
           element2Add = New XElement(elementNames(i).ToString)
           If i = 0 Then
                isaElement.Element("DOC").Add(elementNames(i))
           Else
                lastElement.Element(lastElement.Name).Add(element2Add)
           End If
      Next
      isaElement.Save("c:\temp.xml")
      Me.Close()

 End Sub
```

' I really appreciate the help. I have been working with this all week.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```vb
Dim names = New String() { "LINE1", "LINE2", "LINE3" }

Dim doc = New XDocument
Dim previous As XContainer = doc

For Each name In names
    Dim current = new XElement(name)
    previous.Add(current)
    previous = current
Next
```

The code above produces the following XML, which I think is what you wanted:

```xml
<LINE1>
  <LINE2>
    <LINE3 />
  </LINE2>
</LINE1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to achieve is to add each line as a child element of the previous element then you could use something like this.

```
Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
stringBuilder.AppendLine("LINE1")
stringBuilder.AppendLine("LINE2")
stringBuilder.AppendLine("LINE3")

Dim stringReader As New StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString())

Dim document As New XDocument
Dim previousElement As XElement = Nothing

Dim line As String = stringReader.ReadLine()
While Not line = Nothing

    Dim element As New XElement(line)
    If previousElement Is Nothing Then
        document.Add(element)
    Else
        previousElement.Add(element)
    End If

    previousElement = element

    line = stringReader.ReadLine()

End While

Dim xml As String = document.ToString()
```